# icCube connecting to Excel 2016

Tags: xmla, iccube, excel-2016

I get the following warning when I open a xlsx spreadsheet, connected to iccube, in Excel 2016. It works in Excel 2013 but not 2016.

> Excel cannot connect to your database with the driver you specified in your data source. The driver does not support OLAP-provider capabilities required by Excel.
>
> Consult your system administrator or contact your OLAP database vendor.

Is there an odc connection option that needs to be flagged or do I need to install a previous OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services driver?

Comment: We've open a bug for this http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-186 , will be fixed asap

Comment: we found the problem, will be fixed in the next release coming shortly

Comment: for info, 5.1.3 that fixes Excel 2016 issue has been released today

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue - [entry](http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-186) - , Excel changed a bit the way they use XMLA. We've fixed the issue and it will be available in the next release that is planned shortly.

No workaround other than upgrading icCube to 5.1.3 or above.